# Why am I getting a "Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" error

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm trying to create a loan calculator but for some reason I keep getting "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" error

```
iniLoan=float(input("What is the loan"))
interestRate=float(input("What is the interest rate?"))
numberOfpayments=int(input("For how many years is it?"))

monthly=float(iniLoan)*[float(interestRate)*(int(1)+float(interestRate))*int(numberOfpayments)\
]/[(int(1)+float(interestRate))*int(numberOfpayments)-int(1)]

print("The monthly payment is {0:f} " .format(monthly))
```

Comment: Break up the complex expression into simpler expressions - with useful intermediate variable names - and you will find the error: which is just what the message reports. There should be *no* `float(..)` or `int(..)` constructs after the initial reading in of text to variables, which will greatly remove a lot of the cruft as well. (Note: `list * int` in Python is *not* vector multiplication - and `list * float` is thus forbidden as it makes no sense!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` and `[]` aren't interchangable - you should only use `(` and `)` for mathematical expressions. Just rewrite `monthly` with the right type of brackets, and you should be OK:

```
monthly=float(iniLoan)*(float(interestRate)*(int(1)+float(interestRate))*int(numberOfpayments)\
)/((int(1)+float(interestRate))*int(numberOfpayments)-int(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Further explanation of why Mureinik's answer is correct.
 **Using brackets `[]` creates a list.** 
The error you are receiving:
`can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` is saying you cant multiply a list (sequence) by a float. 
**For example:** 
`['a', 34, 'cow] * 2.365` doesn't make any sense. 
How do you make 2.365x that list? You can't. 

The same logic is true even if the list just holds a number: 
`[5] * 4.3` will cause the same error for the same reason.
**Solution:**
You just want to use good ol' parenthesis `()` when you want to have the value inside calculated together.